# R - Creating DFs (tibbles) in a loop. How to rename them and columns inside, to include date? (I do it with eval(..), but is there a better solution?)

Tags: r, dplyr, eval, rename, tibble

I have a loop, that creates a tibble at the end of each iteration, **tbl**. Loop uses different date each time, **date**.

Assume:

```
tbl <- tibble(colA=1:5,colB=5:10)  
date <- as.Date("2017-02-28")  

> tbl
# A tibble: 5 x 2
   colA  colB
  <int> <int>
1     1     5
2     2     6
3     3     7
4     4     8
5     5     9
```

(contents are changing every loop, but **tbl**, **date** and all columns (**colA**, **colB**) names remain the same)

The output that I want needs to start with **output** - **outputdate1**, **outputdate2** etc.
With columns inside it as **colAdate1**, **colBdate1**, and **colAdate2**, **colBdate2** and so on.

At the moment I am using this piece of code, which works, but is not easy to read:

```
eval(parse(text = (
  paste0("output", year(date), months(date), " <- tbl %>% rename(colA", year(date), months(date), " = 'colA', colB", year(date), months(date), " = 'colB')")
)))
```

It produces this code for eval(parse(...) to evaluate:

```
"output2017February <- tbl %>% rename(colA2017February = 'colA', colB2017February = 'colB')"
```

Which gives me the output that I want:

```
> output2017February
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  colA2017February colB2017February
             <int>            <int>
1                1                5
2                2                6
3                3                7
4                4                8
5                5                9
```

Is there a better way of doing this? (Preferably with dplyr)
Thanks!

Comment: Repeat with me "`eval(parse())` is evil. A `list` of data.frames is what I should create."

Comment: I know that eval(parse(..)) is not the best... Hence my question to try and move away from it... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This avoids `eval` and is easier to read:

```
ym <- "2017February"
assign(paste0("output", ym), setNames(tbl, paste0(names(tbl), ym)))
```

### Partial rename

If you only wanted to replace the names in the character vector `old` with the corresponding names in the character vector `new` then use the following:

```
assign(paste0("output", ym), 
   setNames(tbl, replace(names(tbl), match(old, names(tbl)), new)))
```

### Variation

You might consider putting your data frames in a list instead of having a bunch of loose objects in your workspace:

```
L <- list()
L[[paste0("output", ym)]] <- setNames(tbl, paste0(names(tbl), ym))
```

`.GlobalEnv` could also be used in place of `L` (omitting the `L <- list()` line) if you want this style but still to put the objects separately in the global environment.

### dplyr

Here it is using dplyr and rlang but it does involve increased complexity:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

.GlobalEnv[[paste0("output", ym)]] <- tbl %>% 
                    rename(!!!setNames(names(tbl), paste0(names(tbl), ym)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The "assign" part works well.
I didnt put it in the question, but is it possible to change only specific columns, and not all of them? (Right now setNames changes all columns).
I could rename columns outside the setNames, but maybe it's possible to do that in that one line?

Comment: Have added partial rename section.

Comment: Great, that works perfectly, thanks!  
And I will try Variation and dplyr versions too. (What is !!! there?)

Comment: `rename` and other dplyr functions use non-standard evaluation which require hard-coding of column names.  The rlang !! and !!! and related functions are a a way around that.  See rlang package vignette and help files.